# Swift catch enum case with binding

Tags: swift, exception, enums, pattern-matching

If I have a custom error

```
enum MyError: Error {
  case error1
  case error2
}
```

I can catch all errors of that type and bind a variable:

```
do {
} catch let e as MyError {
} catch {
  // everything else
}
```

or I can catch a specific error without binding a variable

```
do {
} catch MyError.error1 {
} catch {
  // everything else, including MyError.error2
}
```

but how do I catch a specific error *and* bind a variable?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a variable inside a catch to be the specific error case of a specific type of error.

If so, you can do this:

```
do {
    try something()
} catch let err1 as MyError where err1 == .error1 {
    print(err1)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: How is this different to `} catch MyError.error1 {` in a real use case?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I suppose there could be a use case where multiple errors match `where err.rawValue > 3` where it would be somewhat useful. When I replied I wasn't concerning myself with whether this was a real case :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This is useful if you want to do something with the error inside the block but not duplicate the `MyError.error1` code

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the following:

```
    do {
        throw(MyError.error2)
    } catch let error as MyError {
        switch error {
        case .error1:
            print("error 1 happened")
            return
        case .error2:
            print("error 2 happened")
            return
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
        return
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question slightly. I want a catch-all at the end, so your approach would force me to duplicate that code in the `.error2` case. Or is there a way to get from .error2 to the catch-all?

Comment: I think it wouldn't force you to duplicate the code. Since the MyError types are handled first in the first catch block, the catch-all part wouldn't run.